# Are these proofs of the 1st and 3rd Laws of Logarithms valid?

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

**Disclaimer**: I dont mean that I've discovered a conceptually completely different way of proving those laws, of course. I just found myself proving them like this and then realized that they're presented differently in my sources, so I'm wondering whether my presentations are valid, because they makes more sense intuitively to me.

**A)** Proof that $\log_b xy = \log_bx + \log_by$:

Let $x = b^a$ and $y = b^c$

Then, $\log_bxy = \log_b b^ab^c = \log_bb^{a+c} = a+c = \log_bb^a + \log_bb^c = log_bx+log_by$

My question here is whether it's ok for me to assume that I can always find $b^a$ to represent $x$ and $b^c$ to represent $y$ (is there a proof of this, by the way?).

**B)** Proof that $\log_bx^n = n \log_bx$

Here I wanted to prove this law using the first law, as such:

$\log_bx^n = \log_b(x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_n) = \log_bx_1 + \log_bx_2 + ... + \log_bx_n = n \cdot \log_bx$

Is this a valid proof? It makes sense to me but it seems a step is missing between the last two to make it airtight.

EDIT: Beyond just validity, I welcome any criticism of elegantness, formatting, etc..

Comment: If $x,y,b$ are all positive and $b\not = 1$ then I think what you suggest works, though I tend to think your subscripts in B might be unnecessary and potentially confusing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a new approach. [logarithmic Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, these are fine.

In the first, supposing that there exists $a$ such that $b^a = x$ is the same as saying the exponential function $b^{(\cdot)}$ *surjects* onto the positive reals (assuming that $x > 0$ throughout). We can rigorously prove this. One way is to show that $b^x$ as a function of $x$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} b^x = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} b^x = \infty$. Then the intermediate value theorem gives you what you need.

The other clear method of showing it involves showing that the domain of the log function contains all positive numbers, and that the logarithm is the inverse function of the corresponding exponentiation.

Which you prefer might depend on what your definitions of log and exponentials are.

In the second, it's a bit unfortunate that your displayed proof only works for integer $n$, when it holds in much greater generality. You shouldn't use $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ to refer to $n$ copies of $x$, since they're all the same $x$. If you want to highlight that there are $n$ copies, you might use
$$ \log_b x^n = \log_b (\underbrace{x \cdot x \cdots x}_{n \text{ copies}} ).$$

Comment: Ah, great point about integer values of $n$ only, thank you. I think it comes down to my not having a good intuition at all for fractional exponents.
About the subscripts of $x$, do they imply that all of those values, $x_1, x_2, ...$ are different?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff yes, they do

Comment: Thank you. Can you see a way to prove the general version (not just for integers) of the third law using the first law the way I tried to do?

Comment: You can prove it for rational exponents pretty easily by choosing things like $y = x^{1/m}$, and then considering $y^n$. Getting to irrational exponents is a bit harder, but if you believe in continuity arguments then you're fine. (Or you can look at the variety of other proofs for these facts)

Comment: Thank you, I guess I liked this way because it relates to my intuition of what logs are more than the other proofs I've read, but I'll look at different approaches and try to make them as intuitive.